# Want to use mongoose updateOne but it is not updating

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to update the type: reported to type: pending under the reportStatus, but when I try it on postman I keep on getting

> n:1 ,n:modified:1 and ok:1

```
 report: [
      {
        category: {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: "CrimeCategory",
          required: true,
        },

        location: {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: "Location",
          required: true,
        },
        reportText: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
        reportStatus: {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed,
          default: function () {
            return [
              { type: "reported", date: new Date(), isCompleted: true },
              { type: "pending", isCompleted: false },
              { type: "investigating", isCompleted: false },
              { type: "solved", isCompleted: false },
            ];
          },
        },
      },
    ],
```

This is the controller where I am trying to update the types that is in the model, what am I doing wrong?

```
const crimeReport = require("../../model/crimereport");

exports.updateReport = (req, res) => {
  crimeReport
    .updateOne(
      { _id: req.body.reportId, "report.reportStatus": req.body.type },
      {
        $set: {
          "report.reportStatus.$": [
            {
              type: req.body.type,
              date: new Date(),
              isCompleted: true,
            },
          ],
        },
      }
    )
    .exec((error, report) => {
      if (error) return res.status(400).json({ error });
      if (report) {
        res.status(200).json({ report });
      }
    });
};
```

The postman post request:

```
{
    "reportId": "607b2b25876fa73ec4437440",
    "type":"pending"

}
```

This is the post result from postman:

```
{
    "report": {
        "n": 0,
        "nModified": 0,
        "ok": 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you got the solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like, you are sending `reportId` in the body of post request as a string while the Mongodb document's id is of type `ObjectId`. You need to typecast the reportId into ObjectId, before querying to Mongodb. Since you are using Mongoose, this is the way it should be done:

`mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.reportId)`